# Meteor fire an event after Session.set

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

I want to focus an input box in my template after `Session.set("quizStarted", true);`

```
Template.quiz.startQuiz = function(){
    return Session.get("quizStarted");
 }

startQuizAnimate = function(){
    Session.set("quizStarted", true);

    $('.answerBox').focus();   //THIS LINE DOES NOT FOCUS
 }

Template.quiz.events({
  'click #startQuiz' : function(){
    startQuizAnimate();
  }
}


<template name="quiz">

 <button id="startQuiz">Start!</button>

  {{#if startQuiz}}

    <form class="answer">
      // I want to focus this input text
      <input type="text" class="answerBox" name="text" placeholder="Type your answer here" />
    </form>
  {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

The block inside `{{#if startQuiz}}` contains the input I want to focus on, but I have to call it after `Session.set("quizStarted", true);` finishes rendering. How can I write this with Meteor's best practices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Tracker.afterFlush` to register custom code to be run once every computations currently invalidated have been rerun, in particular the reactive template computation responsible for rerendering the template and insert the form markup after `{{#if startQuiz}}` becomes truthy.

```
function startQuizAnimate(){
  Session.set("quizStarted", true);
  Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
    $('.answerBox').focus();
  });
}
```

Comment: you saved me a great headache, this is the perfect solution!

Comment: `Tracker.afterFlush` sure seems to solve a lot of people's problems, doesn't it? :)